# getAttachments() in GmailApp doesn't include linked files from GDrive

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api, gmail-addons

I am developing an add-on for Gmail. I use Google Apps Script builtin service GmailApp to fetch data from Gmail servers. I have a need to read both attachments and files linked from GDrive in a message.

The builtin [GMailMessage.getAttachments()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-message#getAttachments()) is returning only the standalone attachments but not the files linked from GDrive. The intention of the API is right, those are not attachments. But I just wanted to know is there a way I can query Gmail to fetch me those linked files.

I have considered the following solution:

- Decode the body. Extract the file id from it. Query DriveApp to get the file data.

Would be great if there is a better solution than this.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Have you looked at the message data as parsed by the Gmail API (via the advanced service / APIs Explorer)? It may be easier to access what you want that way, or perhaps not.

Comment: Yeah, I had a look at the response from [Users.messages: get](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get). It had the body split into parts and one of the part contained the drive link (for the sample mail I checked against). I had to decode this part and retrieve the link from it.