# Retrieving links to Drive documents from an email

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-api, gmail-addons

I am developing an addon for Gmail using AppsScript. One of the use cases of my addon is to retrieve the Gdrive linked documents which are in the e-mail.

Requirement:

Fetch email along with linked Gdrive attachments (>25MB) using GMailApp service (API documentation).

Need clarification:

I tried following approaches:

- GMailMessage.getAttachments() API which returns only the gmail attachments (<25MB) along with inline images.
- Parsing the email to retrieve the links and fileIds from them.

Is there any other API methods which I can use to achieve my use case?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55182238/getattachments-in-gmailapp-doesnt-include-linked-files-from-gdrive

Comment: @tehhowch Yes, no answer for that too.

Answer (score 0):

Links to Google Drive attachments are included in the source of the email. You can retrieve the raw content of the message using getRawContents(), and then parse it to search for Google Drive links. Working example:

```
  var thread = GmailApp.getInboxThreads(0,1)[0]; // Get first thread in inbox
  var message = thread.getMessages()[0]; // Get first message
  var htmlContent = message.getRawContent();
  Logger.log(htmlContent); // Log contents of the body

  var regex = /<(https[^>]*)>/g
  var results = htmlContent.match(regex);

  // Log each attachment link
  for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    Logger.log(results[i]);
  }
```

Raw content of an email:
[image: Raw content of an email]

Comment: Thanks for the response. Sorry that I missed to mention this in my question. I have tried this approach too. But I am looking for a more stable solution like an API from GMail side, which I could call for fetching this information instead of working on the HTML output, which could change anytime.